# How to set up this specific vimrc configuration

Tags: vim

I don't have much experience and I hope you guys can help me, because nobody around me can.

I am starting to work with Vim and I am setting my vimrc now, but that's a lot of work, and I want to focus on learning how to use it, and not waste my time for now on configuring simple stuff like text highlighting or indentation, things that everybody has... So I want to use this vimrc https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim which is generally provided by Steve Francia.

The problem is that he uses gitHub, and I want to have everything locally on my machine, can you tell me how to do that? Including all the plugins, of course.

Comment: 0_o Git repositories **are** local. That's the whole point of a DVCS. Install git and clone the repository.

Comment: Thanks, at least this gives me some direction in which to start reading and writing. I'm sorry that these questions are seem obviously stupid to you, but I am a noob and everybody is using terminology that I don't know ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just turning on the indent and syntax features you mentioned, and call it it a day. Don't worry right now about extensions you don't need that load themselves.

```
$ cat > $HOME/.vimrc
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
^D
$
```

Yes, I use something like his setup (I use Pathogen) and sure, it is kind of cool to just be able to clone a git module into my `.vim/bundle` directory, but that's an elaborate configuration that's just a distraction for you right now.

Comment: So can you please at least direct me to some reading materials or give me some direction in which to solve this. I tried downloading the files on git but I couldn't do the installation ...

Comment: Well, sure. Steve is using vundle: https://github.com/gmarik/vundle and I am using Pathogen: https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen -- If you follow the instructions on one of those two github pages you can install one. They can traverse directories of github repo clones to install features without needing to merge them into a single vim configuration. Build up your vim setup one thing at a time so you understand it.

Answer (score 2):

> ... that's a lot of work ...

Be prepared to continually spend some time to learn new Vim skills and improve your configuration (or chose a different editor / IDE that offers a more carefree, but also more restricted experience). Bram Moolenaar, the creator of Vim, has made a compelling case for [good habits of text editing](http://www.moolenaar.net/habits.html). Trust me, it's not a waste of time, but you need to overcome your need for instant gratification.

Comment: Sorry I took the liberty of editing your answer but the information included in that document is too valuable: a link was needed.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute minimum you need for programming in Vim is in the accepted answer. I'd add `set hidden` and a few others to the mix but you don't *need* much more. Especially weird shortcuts that hide native features or useless Git integration plugins.

Don't install any plugin from the start, actually, especially piles of crap like that kind of "distribution". Follow `$ vimtutor`, multiple times if needed. Learn how to use `:help`. Don't copy anyone else's vimrc verbatim and, if you take something from a random vimrc on the net, read the relevant part of the documentation to be sure that you understand what it does, how it does it and why. Your `~/.vimrc` and `~/.vim/` will grow and shrink with you, as you go. That's how it's done.

If you are looking for beginner-level info, [LearnVim](https://github.com/dahu/LearnVim) is a rather nice introduction to Vim that you install as part of Vim's documentation. I'd suggest you install it and read it carefully: it's opinionated but full of low-level information that will doubtlessly help you in the future. I sure would have loved reading it when I started.

Like Ingo said, if all that seems overwhelming nobody will mock you for deciding to use another editor/IDE. Of all my team, I'm the only one who uses Vim (hell, I don't even use it for everything) and the code we write is equally good and/or bad.

Anyway, if you *really* want to go the "distribution" route, you'll have to learn [Git and Github's basics](https://help.github.com/) and follow [the instructions](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim#installation) provided by the distribution's maintainer.